# Where can I find detailed rules and guidelines?

Tags: support

I seem to have fallen afoul of some of the rules on Stack Exchange.  I did my best to read the guidelines in the 'tour'.  Where can I find a more detailed list of rules and guidelines for using this site?

Comment: [FAQ for Stack Exchange sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites)

Comment: Go through the [help] articles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check out the [Help Center](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help) articles (there is one per site) or the [FAQ for Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites) for further detail on the rules and guidelines.

Comment: I think the per site meta shouldn't be ruled out and maybe the blog for historical background/evolution of rules and guidance.

Answer (score 1):

The [Tour](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tour) of any site, using this one as an example, ends with:

> Looking for more in-depth information on the site? [Visit the Help Center](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help)

so visiting the Help Center is the clearly indicated next step if you are seeking more advice on how a site works.

Comment: Indeed, but I couldn't find the help center web page.

Comment: @HuwEvans Which site did you look at the Tour from?  As far as I know every Tour links to its corresponding Help Center.

Comment: Oh the link was their, but I couldn't find the tour again once I closed the tab.  I found it now under help.